# What does Augmenting path,cycle and Residual Arc,Graph mean in graph theory?

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, max-flow

While watchin lecture slide on Min Cost Max Flow I came across these term(no explanation in slide).
Augmenting path
Augmenting cycle
Residual Arc and
Residual Graph
What does it mean, except first I do not get much about last three on doing google.